# How to improve regularity of weak solution with Fourier transform?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am working on the following problem.

Let $f\in L^{2}(\Omega)$,where $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a bounded region with smooth boundary.Show that if u is a weak solution to
$$\Delta u=f,\text{in}\,\Omega,\quad f=0,\text{in}\,\partial{\Omega}.$$
Then $u\in H^{2}(\Omega)$ and
$$||u||_{H^{2}}\leq C ||f||_{L^{2}}.$$

The book gives the hint:Use the Fourier transform and Plancherel Theorem.

But I cannot see how can I use Fourier transform since their are no function in Schwartz space.

I tried to take a smooth approximating series $u_{n}\to u,\text{in} H^{1}_{0}.$But I cannot use Fourier transform to $u_{n}$ since I don't know too much about this series.

Any help will be thanked.

Comment: Since the Fourier transform preserves the $L^2$ inner product in Schwartz space, you can extend it to all $L^2$: it is a standard result and you can find it in pretty much any analysis book introducing Fourier transform.

Comment: From which book is this problem from